# Having Groups based on distinct count of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follow :

```
+-------------+-----------+------+
| GroupNumber | TeamName  | Goal |
+-------------+-----------+------+
|           1 | Sales     | ABC  |
|           1 | Sales     | ABC  |
|           1 | Sales     | ABC  |
|           1 | Design    | XYZ  |
|           2 | Design    | XYZ  |
|           2 | Sales     | XYZ  |
|           2 | technical | XYZ  |
|           2 | Support   | XYZ  |
|           3 | Sales     | XYZ  |
|           3 | Sales     | XYZ  |
|           3 | Sales     | XYZ  |
+-------------+-----------+------+
```

I want to output only the groups that have unique teams greater than 3.
Only group 2 has this condition so the output is :

Expected Output:

```
+-------------+-----------+------+
| GroupNumber | TeamName  | Goal |
+-------------+-----------+------+
|           2 | Design    | XYZ  |
|           2 | Sales     | XYZ  |
|           2 | technical | XYZ  |
|           2 | Support   | XYZ  |
+-------------+-----------+------+
```

not sure how to utilize this in subquery

```
SELECT count(Distinct(TeamName))
  FROM mytable
  group by [GroupNumber]
  HAVING COUNT(Distinct[TeamName])>3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put it in a Subquery:

```
select * 
from mytable
where [GroupNumber] in
 (
   SELECT [GroupNumber]
   FROM mytable
   group by [GroupNumber]
   HAVING COUNT(Distinct[TeamName])>3
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
 SELECT *
 FROM mytable where GroupNumber in (select GroupNumber 
 FROM mytable group by TeamName
 HAVING COUNT(TeamName)>3)
```

Comment: I want the output like in the question not just the count number

Comment: Posted as you required